# Ubuntu 18.10 with i3: How to automatically scale display

Tags: xorg, lightdm, display-resolution, xrandr, i3-wm

I'm running ubuntu 18.10 with i3 and lightdm. I have a 1440p screen on my laptop so when I boot up normally everything is scaled wrong. I can fix it with `xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 2x2`. However, I have to do this manually every time I log in (and doesn't apply to the login screen). Is there a way to set this permanently (or just automatically set it on boot or something)?

Comment: Why are you running lightdm instead of gdm3?

Comment: I started using it because I was having some issues related to logind... though I just switched back and they seem to have solved themselves? (for now at least...)

Comment: It would have been helpful if I was running GNOME or the default ubuntu environment but it did not solve my problems when running i3. Switching back to gdm3 seems helped (though I now have some logind issues again, which I'll try to figure out elsewhere)

Comment: What is i3? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: It's a tiling [window manager](https://i3wm.org/) -- I'm essentially using it as my desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Displays` setting panel...

[image]

Or in GNOME Tweaks...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `i3` config file:

```
~/.config/i3/config
```

Put this command:

```
exec --no-startup-id "exec xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 2x2"
```

More information You can find in the official documentation :
https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#exec